# Probability that Three Pieces Form a Triangle

Tags: python, mathematics

I wrote some code to estimate the solution to the following problem:

> If you break a line segment at two random points, what is the probability that the new line segments can form a triangle?

The code is relatively simple, and it works. However, I can't shake the feeling that each of the three functions I've created could be written more "Pythonically." For example, the first function (`can_form_triangle`) explicitly writes out the combinations of pairs from `(a, b, c)` and then compares them to the element of `(a, b, c)` which is not in the pair. There must be a way to express this more succinctly, more elegantly — more Pythonically.

To be clear, I'd just like advice on refactoring the code to be more elegant/Pythonic. I am not looking for advice on how to change the actual functionality to solve the problem more efficiently.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from random import random


def can_form_triangle(a, b, c):
    '''Determines if lengths a, b, and c can form a triangle.

    Args:
        a, b, c: Number representing the length of a side of a (potential) triangle

    Returns:
        True if all pairs from (a, b, c) sum to greater than the third element
        False otherwise
    '''
    ab = a + b
    ac = a + c
    bc = b + c

    if (ab > c and ac > b and bc > a):
        return True

    return False


def try_one_triangle():
    '''Simulates breaking a line segment at two random points and checks if the segments can form a triangle.

    Returns:
        True if the line segments formed by breaking a bigger line segment at two points can form a triangle
        False otherwise
    '''
    first_point = random()
    second_point = random()
    sorted_points = sorted((first_point, second_point))

    return can_form_triangle(sorted_points[0], sorted_points[1] - sorted_points[0], 1 - sorted_points[1])


def estimate_triangle_probability():
    num_success = num_attempts = 0
    for _ in range(10000000):
        num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
        num_attempts += 1

    print('Success:', num_success)
    print('Attempts:', num_attempts)
    print('Ratio:', num_success / (num_attempts))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    estimate_triangle_probability()
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! In your `can_form_triangle()` you can directly `return ab > c and ac > b and bc > a`

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. you might want to add some more and make that an answer.

Comment: Actually `return ab > c or ac > b or bc > a`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Direct boolean return

As @Grajdeanu Alex says, this:

```
if (ab > c and ac > b and bc > a):
    return True

return False
```

can simply be

```
return ab > c and ac > b and bc > a
```

### Type hints

```
def can_form_triangle(a, b, c):
```

can be

```
def can_form_triangle(a: float, b: float, c: float) -> bool:
```

### Sort unpack

```
first_point = random()
second_point = random()
sorted_points = sorted((first_point, second_point))

return can_form_triangle(sorted_points[0], sorted_points[1] - sorted_points[0], 1 - sorted_points[1])
```

can be

```
    first_point, second_point = sorted((random(), random()))

    return can_form_triangle(first_point, second_point - first_point, 1 - second_point)
```

### Digit triples

10000000 is more easily read as `10_000_000`.

### Attempt looping

`num_attempts` will evaluate to `10_000_000` so it's not worth tracking unless you add an early-exit mechanism.

The whole loop can be replaced with

```
num_success = sum(
    1
    for _ in range(10_000_000)
    if try_one_triangle()
)
```

### Redundant parentheses

```
print('Ratio:', num_success / (num_attempts))
```

does not need the inner parens.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. I didn't know you could write `10000000` as `10_000_000`. That's pretty cool.

Comment: @JoshClark: [It's Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep515).

Answer (score 3):

Quite nicely done. However there is always room for improvement. In order of severity

## Looping

You do

```
def estimate_triangle_probability():
    num_success = num_attempts = 0
    for _ in range(10000000):
        num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
        num_attempts += 1
```

If you were to need the loop counter inside the loop you would rather do

```
def estimate_triangle_probability():
    num_success = 0
    for num_attempts in range(10000000):
        num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
```

As you do not need the counter inside the loop but using the value after the loop as 'number of runs' you shall do

```
def estimate_triangle_probability():
    num_success = 0
    num_attempts = 10000000
    for _ in range(num_attempts):
        num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
```

Looping with extra counters is very error prone. you should really avoid that.

As we already touch this code we also introduce `num_attempts` as parameter which gives nice testabilty

```
def estimate_triangle_probability(num_attempts):
    num_success = 0
    for _ in range(num_attempts):
        num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
```

Another minor readability improvement is the ternary if

```
num_success = 0
for _ in range(num_attempts):
    num_success += 1 if try_one_triangle() else 0
```

which in this case is imho more readable in the form

```
num_success = 0
for _ in range(num_attempts):
    if try_one_triangle():
        num_success += 1
```

Differently we can eliminate the explicit loop for a comprehension

```
num_success = sum(1 for _ in range(num_attempts) if try_one_triangle())
```

So we get rid of the counter initialization and increment.

## Return boolean expressions

You do

```
if (ab > c and ac > b and bc > a):
    return True

return False
```

which is an 'anti-pattern'. Instead do

```
return ab > c and ac > b and bc > a
```

## Temporary variables

You do

```
ab = a + b
ac = a + c
bc = b + c

if (ab > c and ac > b and bc > a):
    # ...
```

which has no better readability or documentation. There is nothing wrong with

```
if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
    # ...
```

The same goes for

```
first_point = random()
second_point = random()
sorted_points = sorted((first_point, second_point))
return can_form_triangle(sorted_points[0], sorted_points[1] - sorted_points[0], 1 - sorted_points[1])
```

which may read

```
sorted_points = sorted(random(), random())
return can_form_triangle(sorted_points[0], sorted_points[1] - sorted_points[0], 1 - sorted_points[1])
```

There is good reason for temporaries if the name of the temporary serves documentation. Here the names do not add value.

To improve readability of the return expression we do

```
x, y = sorted((random(), random()))
return can_form_triangle(x, y-x, 1-y)
```

## Overengineered

After removing unnecessary temporaries the remaining code looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from random import random


def can_form_triangle(a, b, c):
    """Determines if lengths a, b, and c can form a triangle.

    Args:
        a, b, c: Number representing the length of a side of a (potential) triangle

    Returns:
        True if all pairs from (a, b, c) sum to greater than the third element
        False otherwise
    """

    return a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a


def try_one_triangle():
    """Simulates breaking a line segment at two random points and checks if the segments can form a triangle.

    Returns:
        True if the line segments formed by breaking a bigger line segment at two points can form a triangle
        False otherwise
    """

    x, y = sorted((random(), random()))
    return can_form_triangle(x, y-x, 1-y)


def estimate_triangle_probability(num_attempts):
    num_success = sum(1 for _ in range(num_attempts) if try_one_triangle())

    print('Success:', num_success)
    print('Attempts:', num_attempts)
    print('Ratio:', num_success / num_attempts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    estimate_triangle_probability(10000000)
```

We notice that most functions have a single line of code. We have docstrings for two one-line helpers but none for the top level `estimate_triangle_probability(num_attempts)`. If we eliminate the two helpers we get

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from random import random


def estimate_triangle_probability(num_attempts):
    num_success = 0
    for _ in range(num_attempts):
        # break a line of length 1 two times to get three segments
        x, y = sorted((random(), random()))
        # segments can form a triangle if all are shorter than half the perimeter
        if all(s < 0.5 for s in (x, y-x, 1-y)):
            num_success += 1
    return num_success / num_attempts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_attempts = 10000000
    ratio = estimate_triangle_probability(num_attempts)
    print('Attempts:', num_attempts)
    print('Ratio:', ratio)
```

Here we also moved output code from the remaining function to main and introduced a return value instead. The final result is is maybe a little too dense for a programming course. Left to do: We could still improve some names. Also the remaining function needs documentation.

Comment: Nice answer. In the last code, I would not even do the division,but let the caller worry about that, and just return `num_success` or a tuple `num_success, num_attempts`. You can also use the fact that a `True` counts as `1` when added to an `int` to rewrite the for-loop to `for _ in range(num_attempts):; x, y = sorted((random(), random())); num_success += all(s < 0.5 for s in (x, y-x, 1-y))`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: Division - I did the division to fit the name and I actually prefer it like that.